# What is the best way to make my buttons on my calculator interactive, so that they can actually add, subtract, etc?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, calculator

I wanted to make a small calculator project for fun to test out my new GUI knowledge with Java Swing API. I created the GUI, but there's a crucial part missing: The math! My Question is, how do I add functionality to each of these buttons? In simpler terms: How do I make the buttons add something to the text box(2+2) when the user clicks the buttons, and then have the system actually add the numbers together and display them for the user?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class basicCalculatorDesign {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        basicCalculatorDesign calc = new basicCalculatorDesign();
        calc.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton one = new JButton("1");
        JButton two = new JButton("2");
        JButton three = new JButton("3");
        JButton four = new JButton("4");
        JButton five = new JButton("5");
        JButton six = new JButton("6");
        JButton seven = new JButton("7");
        JButton eight = new JButton("8");
        JButton nine = new JButton("9");
        JButton zero = new JButton("0");
        JButton plus = new JButton("+");
        JButton minus = new JButton("-");
        JButton divide = new JButton("/");
        JButton multiply = new JButton("*");
        JButton sqrt = new JButton("SqRt");
        JButton percentage = new JButton("%");
        JButton equals = new JButton("=");

        JTextField input = new JTextField();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Basic Calculator");
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, label);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, input);

        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel2);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(210, 260);


        GridBagConstraints right = new GridBagConstraints();
        right.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        GridBagConstraints left = new GridBagConstraints();
        left.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        GridBagConstraints middle = new GridBagConstraints();
        middle.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        right.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        right.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        // add buttons
        panel.add(one, left);
        panel.add(two, middle);
        panel.add(three, right);
        panel.add(four, left);
        panel.add(five, middle);
        panel.add(six, right);
        panel.add(seven, left);
        panel.add(eight, middle);
        panel.add(nine, right);
        panel.add(zero, right);

        panel2.add(equals);
        panel2.add(plus);
        panel2.add(minus);
        panel2.add(divide);
        panel2.add(multiply);
        panel2.add(sqrt);
        panel2.add(percentage);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd look into the ActionListener class. You can use e.getSource() to determine which button was clicked. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: Either use a separate `ActionListener` for each button or better yet, use the [`Action` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: @SaviourSelf Answer modified guys. I would try again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Answer modified guys. I would try again

Comment: That's a lot of `JButtons`, maybe you should use an `ArrayList<Integer>` for the numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to implement this into a single inner class, and then use that inner class multiple times for different buttons.

You can use the same Action (ActionListener) for your number (0-9) buttons. Something like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
    display.replaceSelection( source.getActionCommand() );
}
```

where "display" is the textField that displays the digits and result. This code will just append the digit of the button that was clicked to the display.

For the other buttons you should create separate Actions because they do different functions.

Comment: +1 for another lesson how to use TextActions, please is there full list of or have to search in KeyBindings

Comment: @mKorbel, this answer is not about TextAction or KeyBindings.